# Ranger user sync not syncing user in real time

Tags: apache-ranger

We installed ranger user-sync and able to sync all external users via open LDAP. This user sync is only happening when we restart ranger user sync. I would like to see if user can sync in real-time. Please help me how can I achieve this.

Below properties configured in install.properties. Rest other properties, I kept default.

```
SYNC_SOURCE = ldap
MIN_UNIX_USER_ID_TO_SYNC = 500
MIN_UNIX_GROUP_ID_TO_SYNC = 500
SYNC_INTERVAL = 1
SYNC_LDAP_URL = ldap://<Open LDAP server IP and port>
SYNC_LDAP_BIND_DN = cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
SYNC_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = <password>
SYNC_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE = dc=example,dc=org
SYNC_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE = dc=example,dc=org
SYNC_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE = sub
SYNC_LDAP_USER_OBJECT_CLASS = person
SYNC_LDAP_USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE = uid
SYNC_LDAP_USERNAME_CASE_CONVERSION=none
SYNC_LDAP_GROUPNAME_CASE_CONVERSION=none
SYNC_LDAP_REFERRAL =follow
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154975/ranger-ldap-integration-user-group-sync-issue

Answer (score 0):

@Shailendra. You may need to schedule the restart of ranger or the user sync directly via chron.  I was able to find some info about the usersync sleep time.

Check for and reduce the value of this property in your configuration for the usersync sleep time:

ranger.usersync.sleeptimeinmillisbetweensynccycle ([reference](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/ranger-usersync-timings/td-p/106396))

This article may help too as it suggest a java code to run usersync manually:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Is-there-a-way-to-force-Ranger-user-sync-to-run-manually/td-p/110370