# Ranger LDAP Integration User/Group Sync issue

Tags: ldap, openldap, ambari, apache-ranger

I am using Ranger version 1.2.0.Iam trying to integrate with LDAP user/group sync. Below are the configurations of ranger.

```
Bind User: uid=admin,o=Mobility
Username Attribute : cn
User Object Class​ : inetOrgPerson
User Search Base : ou=Users,o=Mobility
​User Search Filter : (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=?))
User Search Scope : cn
User Group Name Attribute : cn
Group Member Attribute : member
Group Name Attribute : cn
Group Object Class : groupOfNames
Group Search Base : ou=Groups,o=Mobility
Group Search Filter : (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))
```

below is the screenshot of LDAP condig

[image]

Below are the logs iam getting in ranger auth.log

```
11 Feb 2021 16:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder.getGroups() completed with group count: 0
11 Feb 2021 16:51:04  INFO UserGroupSync [UnixUserSyncThread] - End: update user/group from source==>sink
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO UserGroupSync [UnixUserSyncThread] - Begin: update user/group from source==>sink
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder updateSink started
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - Performing user search first
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - extendedUserSearchFilter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(|(uSNChanged>=0)(modifyTimestamp>=1
9700101053000Z))(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=?)))
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder.getUsers() completed with user count: 0
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - extendedAllGroupsSearchFilter = (&(objectclass=groupOfNames)(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=
?))(|(uSNChanged>=0)(modifyTimestamp>=19700101053000Z)))
11 Feb 2021 17:51:04  INFO LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder [UnixUserSyncThread] - LdapDeltaUserGroupBuilder.getGroups() completed with group count: 0
11 Feb 2021 17:51:05  INFO UserGroupSync [UnixUserSyncThread] - End: update user/group from source==>sink
```

Answer (score 0):

Usersync property is wrongly configured.
Here is the fix for it.
https://github.com/apache/ranger/pull/74

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ranger.apache.org/msg00684.html